# How can I get country code on vue tel input?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

**My component**

```
<v-form>
  <v-container>
    <v-row>        
      <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3">
        <vue-tel-input v-model="phone"></vue-tel-input>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
  <v-btn
    color="success"
    @click="submit"
  >
    submit
  </v-btn>
</v-form>
```

When I click submit, I just get phone. How can I get country code too?

[Reference] https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tel-input-vuetify

[Codepen] https://codepen.io/positivethinking639/pen/YzzjzWK?&editable=true&editors=101

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems like `vue-tel-input` provides a `country-changed` event. According to the docs it's even fired for the first time and it returns an object:

```
Object {
   areaCodes: null,
   dialCode: "31",
   iso2: "NL",
   name: "Netherlands (Nederland)",
   priority: 0
}
```

So this event handler can be added to the component and the country code can be stored in the component as you already do for the phone value.

HTML part

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-form>
      <v-container>
        <v-row>        
          <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3">
            <vue-tel-input v-model="phone" v-on:country-changed="countryChanged"></vue-tel-input>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
      <v-btn
        color="success"
        @click="submit"
      >
        submit
      </v-btn>
    </v-form>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

JS Part

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      phone: null,
      country: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    countryChanged(country) {
      this.country = country.dialCode
    },
    submit() {
      console.log(this.phone);
      console.log(this.country);
    }
  }
});
```

Here you can see a working version:
https://codepen.io/otuzel/pen/PooBoQW?editors=1011

NOTE: I don't use Vue on daily basis so I am not sure if this the best practice to modify the data via the event handler.

Comment: I updated my answer. For example, it returns "31" for the Netherlands. Hope that works for you.

Comment: Why is there no `+` symbol? For example I choose America, the country code: `1`. Should `+1`

Comment: @positivethinking Apparently the component uses this list to get the country codes: https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input/blob/master/src/js/data.js
Without the plus sign it should be more flexible to use this data. So you can just add '+' character to the county code like `this.country = '+' + country.dialCode` in the `countryChanged` event handler.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi. I want to ask again :) Do you know how to add a country code search in the country code dropdown? so make it easier for the user

Comment: Hi, you're welcome. About your question, sorry I don't have much idea about that one. Sounds like it needs some modification in the original code of the component. But maybe you can play with the component props and achieve a similar result. I updated my codepen code. This version lets you enter the country code directly to the input field and it shows the matched flag on the left. Hope that helps.

Comment: I make a new question. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58791049/how-can-i-add-search-country-code-on-vue-tel-input

Comment: Okay no problem if you don't do that. I will try it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
<vue-tel-input v-model="phone" v-bind="bindProps"></vue-tel-input>
```

```
data() {
  return {
    phone: null,
    bindProps:{
      mode: 'international'
    }
  }
}
```

It's achievable in `vue-tel-input@3.1.1` by setting prop `mode: 'international'`, in this case, the phone number will always be converted to +123 123 123...

Comment: I check in my package.json. My version is `"vue-tel-input": "^4.0.0"`. Should it works